# Temporary remove in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="stuff">
<span class="to_hide"> blah </span>
<span id="permanent"> like glue </span>
</div>
```

I want to grab the `$(".stuff").text()`, but I don't the `#tmp`'s text

This works fine I do `$(".to_hide").remove()`

But I don't want the removal action to have an effect on the page itself. If I remove it or detach, I need to know where the elements have been (assume many `.to_hide` nodes)

How can I use `.text()` while ignoring `.to_hide`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to use a clone

```js
var text = $(".stuff").clone().find('.to_hide').remove().end().text();
console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stuff">
  <span class="to_hide"> blah </span>
  <span id="permanent"> like glue </span>
</div>
```

---

You can also do - but if you have complex systems and text nodes which are direct descendants of `stuff` this may not work

```js
var text = $(".stuff *").not('.to_hide').text();
console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stuff">
  <span class="to_hide"> blah </span>
  <span id="permanent"> like glue </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make a clone then get text from div

```
var clone =$(".stuff").clone();
clone.find(".to_hide").remove();
var text= clone.text()
console.log(text);
```

[jsBin Example](http://jsbin.com/fazequluvi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to subtract the text you want excluded from the entire chunk of text.

```
var keep = document.querySelector('.stuff').innerText
var exclude = document.querySelector('.to_hide').innerText
var result = keep.replace(new RegExp(exclude, 'g'), '')

alert(result)
```

Ultimately, the complexity of the solution will depend on the DOM you expect to be operating on. Also, you don’t gain much by leaning on a DOM library for this.